# Python write data to Excel

Tags: xlsxwriter

I want to write some data from a CSV to an Excel-Sheet.

Here is my Code:

```
import xlrd
import xlsxwriter
import requests

# download
link="...."
s=requests.get(link).content
c=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')))

book = xlrd.open_workbook("***.xlsx","w")
worksheet = book.sheet_by_index(10)

worksheet.write('B2',5)
workbook.close()
```

Actually i want to use the data from the requested link. But the code still stops on write a simple Issue. It works if i add a new sheet. But i cant write in an existing sheet. Have anyone an idea?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use xlsxwriter worksheet methods with xlrd worksheet objects. You can't do that. If you need a solution where you update an existing xlsx file then have a look at the openpyxl module.

Comment: That helps a lot. Didnt know this libary. THANK YOU